# nginx rewrite for subdomains and https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, https, subdomain

I have rails app that I am moving to https. The app itself redirects subdomains, as follows:

http://www.foo-bar.example.com will redirect to:

http://www.example.com/businesses/foo-bar

There are thousands of these ever-changing "vanity urls", so simply using a wildcard cert will not work.

We are trying to stop cert errors that may occur when someone tries to enter something like:

https://www.foo-baz.example.com

I tried the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845724/nginx-rewrite-for-subsubdomains-to-subdomains) but got the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] empty regex in server name "~" in /etc/nginx/servers/xxxxx/custom.conf:9
```

And here's the line in question:

```
server_name ~ ^(?:.*\.)?(.*)\.example\.com$;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove space between `~` and `^`, that space is important

Comment: See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

Comment: Ah. Thank you, Tarun, and Richard.